# Application crashes when clicking webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I am encountering a new error for me when writing in any text field in webview.

Error message in log is :

> 11-19 16:40:48.063: E/AndroidRuntime(24912):
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: EditText cannot use the ellipsize
>   mode TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE

My code for webview is :

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PLANET_NUMBER);
    View rootView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.webview, container,false);

    // String planet =
    // getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ns_menu_items)[i];
    String planet = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Links)[i];

    mWebView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview);

    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
    // mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/");

    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            mWebView.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            if(mProgress.isShowing()) {
                mProgress.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });

    mProgress = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Loading", 
                                      "Please wait for a moment...");
    url = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_links)[i];
    mWebView.loadUrl(url);
    getActivity().setTitle(planet);

    return rootView;
}
```

Any idea about this error. App crashes on any on click on any form element.

here is xml file :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- The main content view -->

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#1BB1CC"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

activity_main.xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/title_background"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

Webview.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:gravity="center"
     >

</WebView>
```

Comment: As per your error message it shows "EditText cannot use the ellipsize mode". Are you using edittext in your xml layout?

Comment: Can you please post your xml file.

Comment: show your oncreate method of this fragment

Comment: sorry @QuokMoon, can you explain which method?

Comment: are you define onCreate method into fragment if then saw

Comment: I've written onCreateView method above.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this line

```
mWebView.setClickable(true);
```

after this line

```
mWebView = (Webiew) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

Comment: same problem, when I click on any field app crashes.